# How to set Command+ as a key equivalent?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I want to have command-plus as a key equivalent for a menu item, however, when I try to enter command-plus, it shows up as command-shift-equals instead of a plus.  And when I press command-plus, it shows up as command-equals. Does anyone know how I can get around this?

Comment: Not sure about the second part of your question because you press same keys, yet describe the different outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To type a `+` sign you actually have to press Shift+'=', that's why when you put Cmd+ into key equivalent it shows up as Cmd+Shift+=.

Comment: I know that.  The thing is that I want to make it show up as Cmd'+' instead of Cmd'=' or Cmd-Shift-'='.

Comment: You'd deceive a user of your app if he/she tries to press Cmd and '+' without pressing 'Shift'.

Comment: Apple disagrees. See the View menu in Safari, for example.

Answer (score 3):

In Xcode 8.2 when entering a key equivalent, if you hit ⇧⌘= you get a little popup button saying "alternates" inside the field. It presents you ⇧⌘= and ⌘+ as alternates (importantly, this only shows if you enter the key equivalent from the text field in the inspector, not by double-clicking the key equivalent slot for a menu item in IB). This is where I presume you are intended to choose ⌘+ if you want it presented like that.

However, that doesn't actually appear to work at least when compiling my app in macOS Sierra 10.12 / with Xcode 8.2.1. I'm posting this as a solution as the key equivalent looks correct in Interface Builder after doing this, and issue with it happens only during runtime so I assume there is a version of the Xcode build toolchain or Cocoa where this actually works.

Interestingly, editing the storyboard gives the same symptom (the equivalent works fine in IB but shows up blank ):

```
  <menuItem title="Increase Image Size" keyEquivalent="+" id="SCO-e4-3zd">
    <modifierMask key="keyEquivalentModifierMask" command="YES" />
    <connections>
      <action selector="increaseRowHeight:" target="Ady-hI-5gd" id="pu1-6E-HSr"/>
      </connections>
  </menuItem>
```

A third solution has the same runtime symptoms too (assign an outlet to the item and set it in code):

```
    decreaseThumbnailSizeItem.keyEquivalent = "+"
    decreaseThumbnailSizeItem.keyEquivalentModifierMask = NSCommandKeyMask
```

The same works when setting either `NSShiftKeyMask` or `NSAlternateKeyMask` together with `+` as the key.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done programmatically. Connect the menu item to a property ("zoomInItem") in interface builder. Then set the key equivalent when the application is finished launching.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification*)aNotification {
    [self.zoomInItem setKeyEquivalent:@"+"];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a keyboard with a numerical keypad, you could use the numpad `+` key.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the xib file in a text editor add edit the menu item's key equivalent there:

```
<menuItem title="Zoom In" keyEquivalent="+" id="hXP-3c-xDr"/>
```